# How to use lodash sortBy together with custom order comparator

Tags: lodash

I would like to sort an array with a comparator like:

```
function myCustomComparator(a, b){...}
```

It would be like

```
var sorted = myArray.sort(myCustomComparator);
```

But I would like to use it inside a lodash command chain using `sortBy`

How can i use `myCustomComparator` in a Lodash SortBy call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Lodash documentation, it states:

> Creates an array of elements, sorted in **ascending** order by the results of running each element in a collection thru each iteratee.

If anyone can prove me wrong otherwise, I don't think you're able to apply a custom comparator to lodashs' sortBy function.

If it helps, or for anyone stumbling on this, a custom comparator sort function can be achieved with the following snippet.

```
var arr = [ 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 0 ];

function customComparator(a, b) {
    return (a > b) ? -1 : 1;
}

var sorted = arr.sort(customComparator);
```